# git clone from other local user

Tags: git, github

I am following chapters from git-scm.com. I have setup a bare repository at my server git@whateverIP/home/user/git/project.git. I pushed my project from my local machine to the bare repository. I thinks that has worked, because on doing push again gives 0 changes made message.
now I have another user at my server machine. I wish to clone the repository at git@whatever/home/user/git/project.git to this users directory .

I used command git clone git@whateverIP/home/git/savi/git/Dpschool.git and it says

> fatal: repository 'git@198.199.104.102/savi/git/Dpschool.git' does not exist

and I also used git clone git://whateverIP/home/git/savi/git/Dpschool.git and then it says

> errno=Connection refused

I am new @ this, please clear me up on this and suggest some solution

Comment: what protocol are you planning to use to connect to the server? ssh?

Comment: Please give the *exact* command you and the other user used for cloning. Also, please post the "remote" section from .git/config inside your repo. Obfuscate any private data, of course.

Comment: from my local machine yeah SSH, i don't know what i should do other two users are on server(git and live) I will just like to only fetch from bare repository

Comment: @sleske do I have to add remote even if both users are on same machine, anyways I am using clone, that should automatically make it my remote origin
and git remote has empty response for live user

Comment: @XavitojCheema: Yes, using "git clone" will automatically create the remote. Still, please post the requested information, otherwise it's unlikely we can help.

Comment: sorry guys, problem solved, I forgot to put ':' in my server address, 
actually I copied my address my git protocol command :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue with the group of another user.  Please check if the other user is in same group as your's...

Also, if you created the repository (or cloned a new bare repo off an existing one) with

$ git init --shared=group

Git is supposed to handle permissions above and beyond what your default umask provides.

Comment: Also, try this command :

git config core.sharedRepository true